# HQL - Group by entities mapped with joined inheritance type not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

[Group by entities is possible in HQL](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615), but it seems that by entities mapped with joined inheritance doesn't.

```sql
select a, count(r) from Root r join r.a a group by a
```

Executing the above query results in a sql with insufficient columns in group by:

```sql
select
    suba1_.id as col_0_0_,
    count(root0_.id) as col_1_0_,
    suba1_.id as id1_12_,
    suba1_1_.super_data as super_da2_12_,
    suba1_.sub_data as sub_data1_10_ 
from root root0_ 
inner join suba suba1_ on root0_.a_id=suba1_.id 
inner join supera suba1_1_ on suba1_.id=suba1_1_.id 
group by suba1_.id
```

Which gives the following error message:

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: SUPERA1_.SUPER_DATA in statement`

The entities are described as followed:

```java
@Entity
public class Root {
    private @Id Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private SubA a;
}

@Entity
public class SubA extends SuperA {
    private String subData;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class SuperA {
    private @Id Long id;
    private String superData;
}
```

Also if changed the type of Root::a to SuperA, the sql generated by the hql will have the same problem.

**So is group by entities with joined inheritance type possible or am I missing something?**

PS. This hql query does work in case if SuperA is mapped with table per class inheritance type but then fails with the same problem if type of Root::a is changed to SuperA as well.

Hibernate version: `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile`

Comment: What if you do: select a, count(r) from Root r join r.a a group by a

Comment: Actually that was my original query, the "group by a.id" was probrably some other test that copy from. So same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a bit of trickery, to anwser my own question. The missing column for the group by in the sql is the column id of `SuperA`, so the solution would be to include it. I found that possible by mapping the superclass's id with an extra column and reference it in the group by along side the entity.

So, in `SuperA` an extra column mapping `superId` would be added:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class SuperA {
    private @Id Long id;
    @Column(name="id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long superId;
    private String superData;
}
```

And referenced in the group by

```sql
select a, count(r) from Root r join r.a a group by a, a.superId
```

This solution was tested only for HSQLDB and PostgreSQL.